# Random Codebook Generation

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

I do generate a random codebook $\mathcal{C}$ by generating $2^{NC}$ codewords $X^N=[X_1\;X_2\;\cdots\;X_N]$ randomly and independently, each according to some distribution $p_{X^n}(x^n)=\Pi_{i=1}^n p_X(x_i)$ (i.e., the entries of each codeword are i.i.d.~ $p_X$.) The distribution $p_X$ has a finite alphabet $\mathcal{X}$. Now, consider a set $S\subseteq \{1,2,\cdots,N\}$, and define $Z^N=[Z_1\;Z_2\;\cdots\;Z_N]$, where $Z_i=X_i$ if $i\in S$ and $Z_i=``?"$ if $i\notin S$. We say that $X^N$ is consistent with $Z^N$ if $Z^N$ can be obtained from $X^N$ by changing some entries to $``?"$.

I need to show that 
$$
\rm{Pr}\{\text{A codebook } \mathcal{C}=C\text{ which satisfies that for any } Z^N, \text{the number of codewords consistent with } Z^N=M\}\geq 1-\gamma
$$
 for some small $\gamma$ and some fixed $M$.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by P(C|...). What is C? Are you looking for its probability conditioned on the event that follows? What is M? Should this be true for any M?

Comment: Pr{C|} is the probability of the codebook which satisfies the event in the conditioning. And I am trying to show that the statement is true for some fixed $M$, actually, the problem can be seen as if I am seeking for $M$ which makes the statement true. Thank you for the comment, i have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I still don't like (or don't understand) your definition of $Z$, as it would depend on a particular $X$ - (and following that definition $Z$ would always be consistent with $X$!). I tried to think of it as if $Z$ were a fixed arbitrary vector, and label the (randomly generated) codewords as "consistent" if  its Hamming distance to Z is less or equal than $\#S$. But I doubt is this is equivalent - and it does not look good, what if $p_X(x_i)=0$ for some $i$, and I take that value for $Z$?

Comment: A codebook has $2^{NC}$ codewords which are randomly generated and each of length $N$. $Z^N$ is generated from one of these codewords by switching $N-\mu$ arbitrary positions in that codeword to $?$. What I need to show is for any such $Z^N$, the number of codewords in the codebook consistent with this $Z^N$ is a fixed number (with high probability).